# How to save disk usage when cloning git or hg repositories?

Tags: git, mercurial, diskspace

I have cloned few trees into my local disk and it takes too much space from my limited laptop disk. Unlike non-distributed version controls, such as SVN and CVS, when you checkout a git or Mercurial repository you get the whole tree, including the whole history, and since I rarely commit any code into these repositories, but wish to keep them up-to-date, I find that these distributed version control systems waste too much of the local disk.

Few ideas I have so far for eliminating this waste are:

- Create a zfs or btrfs partition on the local disk (probably a loop filesystem as I don't want to keep it too persistent), which should make a better use of duplicated file chunks. This might take too much CPU cycles making it inefficient.
- Give out of using a version control and create a script to download .zip files containing the whole repository daily. This will take too much bandwidth and I'd prefer not to do it.

My ultimate solution would be to use git/hg somehow like we used SVN and CVS — Keep history on the server and locally only the most up-to-date revision, or keep limited history locally, both without breaking everything else so I could see the logs or revert a file to a previous revision and the version control system would fetch the required information from remote if not available locally.

Comment: With hard drives down to $0.04/GB surely this isn't worth your time. :)  Reducing network traffic I understand completely.  Disk storage, not so much.

Answer (score 3):

From the hg clone help information:

```
To pull only a subset of changesets, specify one or more revisions
identifiers with -r/--rev or branches with -b/--branch. The resulting
clone will contain only the specified changesets and their ancestors.
```

You should be able to use HG's revision syntax to limit how many revisions you get assuming you want a little bit more than just the latest.  Use -r tip to just get the tip.

Answer (score 2):

With git you can use `--depth` option to create a shallow copy only.

On the other hand you won't save much space this way: 
http://blogs.gnome.org/simos/2009/04/18/git-clones-vs-shallow-git-clones/

Answer (score 2):

With svn you actually have 2 full, uncompressed copies of the checked out revision (there's a full copy of every file down in `.svn`).  With mercurial you have 1 full, uncompressed copy of the checked out revision and one highly compressed, binary delta representation (down in `.hg/store`).  In a great many cases (diffable text files) the hg clone containing everything will actually be smaller over all then the svn checkout of a single revision.

I don't think your block level deduplication would help at all.  Both Mercurial and Git use very efficient binary deltas which are then compressed leaving almost no redundant information in their stores, and what is there wouldn't be block aligned.

Comment: I am working on Mozilla repositories, which are around 800MB in size, while the .hg/store is around 1.1GB in size, and contains history for about 15 years backward.

Comment: So a svn checkout would be 1.6GB (800+800) and hg is 1.9 (800+1100), that seems about right for that much history.  You're not going to be able to shrink it on the hg side w/o altering history to invalidate current clones, which I imagine is a nonstarter.  If, however, there are some huge branches that are unused and never got merged in you can always exclude them by selectively cloning down the heads/branches you do want with `clone -r`

Answer (score 1):

With mercurial, you can ask for an empty working copy (clone only the .hg folder):

```
hg clone -U <source>
```

See **hg help clone** for more options.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use "hg share". This will allow you to keep only one shared history and multiple revisions checked out as working copies.